# No way to pass variables for reverse url mappings to remoteFunction

Tags: grails

Let say I have a url mappings

"blog/$year/$month/$day" (controller:'blog')

There's no way that I can pass the values for $year, $month and $day to remoteFunction so that it generates the proper url.

without variables, default rule would match and generated url would be like "/controller/action" I know i can pass the params to remoteFunction - so incoming url will match the rule, but how about reverse url mappings - that is used to generate the url for the ajax endpoint.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to put the parameters from the url mapping into a remoteFunction() call, the grails manual says this can be done by accessing the params map in the controller after the request is received:

```
static mappings = {
   "/$blog/$year/$month/$day/$id"(controller: "blog", action: "show")
}
```

> "The individual tokens in the URL would again be mapped into the
>   params object with values available for year, month, day, id and so
>   on."

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings

Comment: I know about this, I think i have mentioned this in original question. Thanks for answer anyway. Its a bug/not implemented yet, I have filed a jira for this.